# Python - Parse YAML dict to get keys by heirarchy

Tags: python, pyyaml

I have a YAML dict in which I need to iterate over the 2nd keys of the heirarchy (/home,/career,/help,/) to find the existance of the key "pass_key".
The location for the "pass_key" will always be fixed (4th heirarchy).

```
api:
  /home:
    post:
      pass_key: some_value
  /career:
    get:
      pass_key: some_value
  /help:
    post:
      pass_key: some_value
```

The challenge is, I am unable to get the key without knowing the name of it as putting asterisk doesn't help here :)
How can I achieve this? Any help would appreciated. Thanks!

```
import yaml

with open(r'./test.yaml') as file:
    api = yaml.load(file, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
    check_key = api['api'][*][*]['pass_key']
    print(check_key)
```

> error line 5
> paths = api['api'][*][*]['pass_key']
> ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're 100% sure about the dictionary structure, as a trivial solution it is possible to use basic loops:

```py
for layer2_vals in api['api'].values():
    for layer3_vals in layer2_vals.values():
        print(layer3_vals['pass_key'])
```

output is

```
some_value
some_value
some_value
```